# How to use Google translator API V2 in iPhone Application?

Tags: ios, iphone, google-translate

Hi I am developing an iPhone application in which I am planing to implement some language translation functionality.I have purchased the google transilator API and got the API key.
Now as per the the tutorial provided by Google I just made an HTTP call using ASIFormDataRequest to this URL "https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=INSERT-YOUR-KEY&source=en&target=de&q=Hello%20world". Unfortunately, it was ended up in an error called Access not configured. Is there any step that I missed ? please help me?

```
    ASIFormDataRequest *translateRequest = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[ValidateClass getURL:@"Conversions.php"]];
    [translateRequest setDelegate:self];
    [translateRequest  setRequestMethod:@"GET"];
    [translateRequest setDidFinishSelector:@selector(didFinishRequest:)];
    [translateRequest setDidFailSelector:@selector(didFailRequest:)];
    [translateRequest setShouldAttemptPersistentConnection:NO];
    [translateRequest setTimeOutSeconds:120];
    [translateRequest startAsynchronous];
```

Comment: Are you actually using your API key?

Answer (score 1):

Just get your Google key and plug it into the [FGTranslator](https://github.com/gpolak/FGTranslator). After that it's a one-liner translate function call.

```
FGTranslator *translator = [[FGTranslator alloc] initWithGoogleAPIKey:@"your_google_key"];

[translator translateText:@"Bonjour!" 
               completion:^(NSError *error, NSString *translated, NSString *sourceLanguage)
{
    if (error)
        NSLog(@"translation failed with error: %@", error);
    else
        NSLog(@"translated from %@: %@", sourceLanguage, translated);
}];
```

Comment: What about error message ? that "The request did not specify any iOS bundle ID. Please ensure that the client is sending it or use the API Console to update your key restrictions."